# Html table filter using 2 dropdowns

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table, dropdown

I'm trying to do something like excel's filter on a html table but I'm really struggling with the second drop-down. In the option "serviços" the drop-down does nothing and it's supposed to be able to pick between the options "cancelar" and "acionar"; and in the option "contratação" it should only appear "alteração potência" once. How can I separate the results into the right options?

```js
function converter() {
      // aqui é a converter uma array apartir da tabela
      // var arrayValores = [];
      $("table tr").each(function() { 
          var arrayRow = [];
          var tableData = $(this).find('td');
          if (tableData.length > 0) {
              tableData.each(function() { arrayRow.push($(this).text()); });
              arrayValores.push(arrayRow);
          }
      }); 
    }

    function filtrar() {
      //variáveis
      let dropdown, table, rows, cells, temas, filtro, subtema;
      dropdown = document.getElementById("temasDropdown");
      subtema = document.getElementById("subtemasDropdown");
      table = document.getElementById("tabela");
      rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      filtro = dropdown.value;

      for (let row of rows) {
        cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        temas = cells[0] || null;  // primeira td ou nada
        if (filtro === "escolher" || !temas || (filtro === temas.textContent)) {
          row.style.display = "";
          subtema.disabled = false;
          for(var i = 0; i < arrayValores.length; i++) {
            var opt = arrayValores[i][1];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            subtema.appendChild(el);
          }
        } else {
          row.style.display = "none";
          subtema.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }

    function filtrar2 () {
      //variáveis
      let dropdown, table, rows, cells, temas, filtro;
      dropdown = document.getElementById("subtemasDropdown");
      table = document.getElementById("tabela");
      rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      filtro = dropdown.value;

      for (let row of rows) {
        cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        temas = cells[1] || null;  // segunda td ou nada
        if (filtro === "escolher" || !temas || (filtro === temas.textContent)) {
          row.style.display = "";
        } else {
          row.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<body onload="converter()">
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="temasDropdown" oninput="filtrar()">
    <option>escolher</option>
    <option>cobranças</option>
    <option>contratação</option>
    <option>faturação</option>
    <option>serviços</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="subtemasDropdown" oninput="filtrar2()" disabled>
    <option>escolher</option>
   </select>
  </div>

<table id="tabela">
  <tr>
    <th>temas</th>
    <th>subtema</th>
    <th>situação</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row0">
          <td class="column0 style0 s">serviços</td>
          <td class="column1 style0 s">acionar</td>
          <td class="column2 style0 s">sue</td>
          <td class="column3 style0 s">tem energia &lt;img src=&quot;01.png&quot;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
          <td class="column0 style0 s">serviços</td>
          <td class="column1 style0 s">cancelar</td>
          <td class="column2 style0 s">sue</td>
          <td class="column3 style0 s">&lt;img src=&quot;02.png&quot;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">
          <td class="column0 style0 s">serviços</td>
          <td class="column1 style0 s">acionar</td>
          <td class="column2 style0 s">pel</td>
          <td class="column3 style0 s">eletrodomesticos &lt;img src=&quot;03.png&quot;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row3">
          <td class="column0 style0 s">contratação</td>
          <td class="column1 style0 s">alterar potência</td>
          <td class="column2 style0 s">aumentar</td>
          <td class="column3 style0 s">pede alteração mas já estava &lt;img src=&quot;04.png&quot;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row4">
          <td class="column0 style0 s">contratação</td>
          <td class="column1 style0 s">alterar potência</td>
          <td class="column2 style0 s">aumentar</td>
          <td class="column3 style0 s">pede alteração cb para envio de form &lt;img src=&quot;05.png&quot;&gt;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement multiple filters in JavaScript using dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812071/how-to-implement-multiple-filters-in-javascript-using-dropdowns)

Comment: It doesn't because the second dropdown needs to show only the options related to the option picked in the first one.